# Proof that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

A similar question was asked here ([Is every open subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ uncountable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326154/is-every-open-subset-of-mathbbr-uncountable)) and here ([Question on the existence of finite open subsets in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466670/question-on-the-existence-of-finite-open-subsets-in-mathbbrk?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

I know nothing of rigorous cardinality, so a proof without that concept would be appreciated (perhaps a modified version of the one found in the second link). If the proof requires cardinality, could you explain why the cardinality of an open subset is the same as $\mathbb{R}^n$: perhaps there exists a bijection we can show?

Comment: I'm confused... how is your question distinct from the two to which you have linked?  What *new* question are you asking?  If you are asking about uncountability, you are *automatically* asking about something which involves cardinality...

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be a point in an open set $U$ in $\mathbb R^{n}$. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $x+t(1,0,0,...,0) \in U$ for $|t| < r$. Define  a map $f:(-r,r) \to U$ by $f(t)=x+t(1,0,0,...,0)$. Verify that this maps is one-to-one. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: Recall that $\frac {2r} {\pi} \arctan x$ is a bijection form $\mathbb R$ onto $(-r,r)$ so  $(-r,r)$ is uncountable.