# Showing all open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are uncountable - extend to general metric space?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I would like to ask for a clarification to the comments to the question here ;

[Proof that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359153/proof-that-every-open-subset-of-mathbbrn-is-uncountable)

As far as I can tell the comment implies for $\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ the mapping $f(\textbf{t})\mapsto \textbf{x}+\textbf{t}(1,0,0,...,0)$ for all $|\textbf{t}|<\epsilon$ is a bijective and hence any open set $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ satisfies $|U|=\aleph$. However I could not make this work for me. Instead, letting $e_{1}=(1,0,0,...,0)$,...,$e_{n}=(0,0,0,...,1)$ be the basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then I believe the mapping $f(\textbf{t})\mapsto \textbf{x}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\textbf{t}\textbf{e}_{i}$ is in fact required. Where am I going wrong? Below is my "proof" of my claim;

Finally, can the basis vector in the referenced question, or (if I am somehow correct) can the basis vectors in my question, be replaced by basis vectors in a general metric space to come up with a very similar proof - i.e. are all open sets in a metric space uncountable?

************ proof - I switched here to $k$ rather than $n$ *******

For any $\textbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $\epsilon>0$ let $B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$ be an open ball centered at $\textbf{y}$. For $i=1,2...,k$ let $\textbf{e}_{i}\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$ be a vector with a $1$ in the $i^{th}$ component and zeroes elsewhere - i.e. $\textbf{e}_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ basis vector for $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Now for all $t_{i}$ satisfying $|t_{i}|<k^{-1/2}\epsilon$ we have

\begin{align*}
d_{k}\left[\textbf{y},\textbf{y}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}t_{j}\textbf{e}_{j}\right]&=
d_{k}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}y_{i}\textbf{e}_{i},\sum_{i=1}^{k}y_{i}\textbf{e}_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}t_{i}\textbf{e}_{i}\right]\\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(y_{i}(\textbf{e}_{i})_{i}-y_{i}(\textbf{e}_{i})_{i}-t_{i}(\textbf{e}_{i})_{i}\right)^{2}}\\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(-t_{i}\right)^{2}}\\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}t_{i}^{2}}\\
&<\sqrt{k\cdot k^{-1}\epsilon^{2}}\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Accordingly for $\textbf{t}:=(t_{1},...,t_{k})$ satisfying $|t_{i}|<k^{-1/2}\epsilon$ for all $i=1,...,k$ (which implies $||\textbf{t}||_{k}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}t_{i}^{2}}<\sqrt{k\cdot k^{-1}\epsilon^{2}}=\epsilon$), if we define the vector $\textbf{y}_{\textbf{t}}=\textbf{y}+\sum_{j=1}^{k}(\textbf{t})_{j}\textbf{e}_{j}$ then the above equation means $d_{k}[\textbf{y},\textbf{y}_{\textbf{t}}]<\epsilon$ which implies $\textbf{y}_{\textbf{t}}\in B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$. Thus defining the mapping $f_{\textbf{y}}:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\longrightarrow B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$, $f_{\textbf{y}}(\textbf{t})\mapsto \textbf{y}_{\textbf{t}}$, we have $f_{\textbf{y}}((-\epsilon,\epsilon))\subseteq B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$. Conversely choose a $\textbf{x}\in B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$ which implies $d_{k}[\textbf{x},\textbf{y}]:=d<\epsilon$, and write $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ in terms of the basis vectors $\textbf{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\textbf{x}_{i}\textbf{e}_{i}$ and $\textbf{y}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\textbf{y}_{i}\textbf{e}_{i}$ so that $d_{k}^{2}[\textbf{x},\textbf{y}]$ can be written as

\begin{align*}
d_{k}^{2}[\textbf{x},\textbf{y}]&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(\textbf{x}_{i}-\textbf{y}_{i}\right)^{2}(\textbf{e}_{i})_{i}^{2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(\textbf{x}_{i}-\textbf{y}_{i}\right)^{2}\\
&=d^{2}\\
&<\epsilon^{2}.
\end{align*}

Defining $t_{i}(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}):=(\textbf{x}_{i}-\textbf{y}_{i})$, and in turn $t(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=\left(t_{i}(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})\right):=((\textbf{x}_{1}-\textbf{y}_{1}),...,(\textbf{x}_{k}-\textbf{y}_{k}))$, using the above equation implies $||t(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})||_{k}=d_{k}[\textbf{x},\textbf{y}]=d<\epsilon$. Thus we have

\begin{align*}
\textbf{x}&=\textbf{y}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(\textbf{x}_{i}-\textbf{y}_{i}\right)\textbf{e}_{i}\\
&=\textbf{y}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}t_{i}(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})\textbf{e}_{i}\\
&=\textbf{y}+\textbf{t}(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})\textbf{e}_{i}\\
&=\textbf{y}_{\textbf{t}(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})},
\end{align*}

for some $||t(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})||_{k}<\epsilon$, which leads to the conclusion $\textbf{x}\in f_{\textbf{y}}((\epsilon,\epsilon))$. Accordingly $B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})\subseteq f_{\textbf{y}}((-\epsilon,\epsilon))$ and so the conclusion $f_{\textbf{y}}((-\epsilon,\epsilon))= B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$ follows. Thus $f_{\textbf{y}}:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\longrightarrow B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$ is an onto function. Furthermore for all $\textbf{s},\textbf{t}\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$ since $(\textbf{y})_{i}+(\textbf{s})_{i}=(\textbf{y})_{i}+(\textbf{t})_{i}$ if and only if $(\textbf{s})_{i}=(\textbf{t})_{i}$ for all $i=1,...,k$ implies $\textbf{y}+\sum_{j=1}^{k}(\textbf{s})_{j}\textbf{e}_{j}=\textbf{y}+\sum_{j=1}^{k}(\textbf{t})_{j}\textbf{e}_{j}$ if and only if $\textbf{s}=\textbf{t}$ then $f_{\textbf{y}}:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\longrightarrow B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$ is also an injective function, and hence is a bijection. Now $|(-\epsilon,\epsilon)|=\aleph$ is well known [and I do not prove it here] and so $|-\epsilon,\epsilon|=|B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})|$ (i.e. $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is equipotent to $B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$). By Definition of equality of set cardinalities we conclude $|(-\epsilon,\epsilon)|=| B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})|=\aleph$.

Comment: ‘are all open sets in a metric space uncountable?‘ No, if your space is not uncountable. No, if you have the discrete metric, as every subset is open. And also you should restrict to non-empty open sets

Comment: One isolated point would be sufficient to get an finite open set.

Comment: The point is to just find an uncountable subset of the neighborhood. You don’t need to go through the effort to make that uncountable subset open, so just embedding a unit interval in one direction is sufficient. Also, you’re making lots of assumptions, so this only really applies to topological manifolds.

Comment: @Eric did you mean "open interval in one direction" rather than "unit interval"?

Comment: Since open balls form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$,  this simplifies to just showing a nonempty open ball is uncountable, which is trivial.

Comment: Ehh, sure - it’s all the same cardinality

Comment: In the linked question, _bijective_ means _bijective with its image_. As Eric says, this shows every non-empty open subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$ _contains an uncountable subset_, hence is itself uncountable.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you Calvin - spectacularly lazy question of me right at the end of my otherwise respectable question! Of course many metric spaces other than $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ can have countable or even finite open sets.

Comment: @Eric Thanks Eric - this did the trick for me! I immediately fixated on showing a bijection between the interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and the entire open ball, and overlooked the sufficiency of a bijection from $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ to the image of $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ under the mapping (thanks to Andrew as well for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $U$ is a non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, let $\vec{x}=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ be a point of $U$. There is some $r>0$ so that $B(\vec{x}, r) \subseteq U$ by the definition of openness.

For $t \in (-r,r)$ define $f(t) = (x_1+t, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \vec{x}+t\vec{e}_1$. Then $$d(f(t), \vec{x}) = \sqrt{t^2 + 0^2 \ldots 0^2} = |t| < r$$

so that $f(t) \in B(\vec{x},r)$ and so $f$ injects the uncountable (size continuum) set $(-r,r)$ into $U$ and so $|U| \ge \mathfrak{c}$ and in fact $|U|=\mathfrak{c}$ (I don't use the old school notation $\aleph$ for continuum but rather the modern $\mathfrak{c}$).

Of course a metric space can be countable too (e.g. $\Bbb Q$ in the Euclidean distance), so the idea that all open balls in *all* metric spaces will be uncountable is nonsense. Metric spaces can have finite open balls even (when they have isolated points; consider $\Bbb Z$ in its usual metric).

Comment: Thanks Henno for the (more compact) confirmation of my proof, and also that this result is confined to Euclidean space and not general metric spaces.

Comment: That proof works in linear spaces over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ with metrics based on norms etc,  so a bit more general than just the Euclidean ones.

Answer (score 1):

Taking onboard all the comments above, it seems every open ball in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ is uncountable [proof below as per the original proposition in the linked question], and since all non-empty open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ are a union of open balls, and unions of uncountable sets produce another uncountable set, then we conclude all non-empty open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ are uncountable.

Finally it has been shown by examples that in general open sets in metric spaces need not be uncountable.

**Proof that all open balls in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ are uncountable**;

For any $\textbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $\epsilon>0$ let $B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$ be an open ball centered at $\textbf{y}$. Let $\textbf{e}_{1}\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$ be the vector with a $1$ in the $1^{st}$ component and zeroes elsewhere - i.e. $\textbf{e}_{1}$ is the $1^{st}$ basis vector for $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Now for all $t$ satisfying $|t|<\epsilon$ we have

\begin{align*}
d_{k}\left[\textbf{y},\textbf{y}+t\textbf{e}_{1}\right]&=
d_{k}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}y_{i}\textbf{e}_{i},\sum_{i=1}^{k}y_{i}\textbf{e}_{i}+t\textbf{e}_{1}\right]\\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(y_{i}(\textbf{e}_{i})_{i}-y_{i}(\textbf{e}_{i})_{i}-t(\textbf{e}_{1})_{i}\right)^{2}}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(-t(\textbf{e}_{1})_{1}\right)^{2}}\\
&=\sqrt{t^{2}}\\
&=|t|\\
&<\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Accordingly if we define the vector $\textbf{y}_{t}=\textbf{y}+t\textbf{e}_{1}$ then the above equation means $d_{k}[\textbf{y},\textbf{y}_{t}]<\epsilon$ which implies $\textbf{y}_{t}\in B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$. Thus defining the mapping $f_{\textbf{y}}:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\longrightarrow B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$, $f_{\textbf{y}}(t)\mapsto \textbf{y}_{t}$, we have $f_{\textbf{y}}((-\epsilon,\epsilon)):=S\subseteq B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})$.

Furthermore for all $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$ since $\textbf{y}+s\textbf{e}_{1}=\textbf{y}+t \textbf{e}_{1}$ if and only if $s=t$ then $f_{\textbf{y}}:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\longrightarrow S$ is an injective and obviously onto function, and hence is a bijection. Now $|(-\epsilon,\epsilon)|=\aleph$ is well known [and I do not prove it here] and so by the definition of comparing cardinalities of sets we have $\aleph=|-\epsilon,\epsilon|\leq |B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})|$. But since $|B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})|<|\mathbb{R}^{k}|=\aleph$ [proof omitted but using bijective functions again] we conclude $\aleph=|B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{y})|$.

**Proof that all open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ are uncountable**;

From the above proof and the definition of comparing cardinalities of sets using bijective functions, the definition of the open sets $\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{R}^{k})$ implies for any $U\in\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{R}^{k})$ that $\aleph\leq |U|$, for choosing any $u\in U$ there exists a $\epsilon_{u}$ such that $B_{\epsilon_{u}}(u)\subseteq U$ where $|B_{\epsilon_{u}}(u)|=\aleph$ which means the bijection $\phi:B_{\epsilon_{u}}(u)\longrightarrow B_{\epsilon_{u}}(u)\subseteq U$, $\phi(u)\mapsto u$, injects a set with cardinality of the continuum into $U$. Furthermore since $|\mathbb{R}^{k}|=\aleph$, the fact that $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{k}$ and the existence of the bijection $\phi:U\longrightarrow U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{k}$, $\phi(u)\mapsto u$ combined the definition of comparing set cardinalities implies $|U|\leq\aleph$. Thus we have $|U|=\aleph$